# how to use DateTime.Parse() to create a DateTime object

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

If I have a string that is in the format `yyyyMMddHHmmssfff` for example `20110815174346225`. how would I create a DateTime object from that String.
I tried the following

```
DateTime TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(Data[1], "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
```

However I get these errors:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments C:\Documents and Settings\rkelly1\Desktop\sd\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 67  29  WindowsFormsApplication1


Error   2   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'    C:\Documents and Settings\rkelly1\Desktop\sd\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 67  53  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
var sDate = "20110815174346225";
var oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(sDate, "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Thank You. I didn't understand IFormatProvider, but I got it from MSDNs site

Comment: Thank you.  One might think that "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture" would be a default for this argument, so it is really useful to know that one can just happily substitute "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture" wherever I see "IFormatProvider".

Answer (score 5):

You would have to use

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(String,String, IFormatProvider);
```

The first argument string is going to be your date.
The second argument string is going to be your format
The third argument is your culture info (which is the IFormatProvider

So you would have

```
DateTime TimeStamp = DateTime.ParseExact(Data[1],"yyyyMMddHHmmssfff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The culture info is "A CultureInfo object that represents the culture used to interpret s. The DateTimeFormatInfo object returned by its DateTimeFormat property defines the symbols and formatting in s." From MSDN.

here's the link for more info. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("[Your Date Here]",
                                        "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff",  
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here's the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the static method `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a date formatted as 20151221T031901

to convert this to date time, I was able to use this format

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20151221T031901","yyyyMMddTHHmmss" , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```